# Verificar si existe un elemento en base de datos mediante ROOM y RXJava

Tags: android, rxjava, room

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar ROOM y RXJava y Android.

Estoy haciendo una prueba en la que desde la aplicación de Android, bajo petición, llamo a un servicio remoto y me devuelve una lista de datos tipo User.
Esa lista se tiene que insertar en la base de datos de la aplicación Android teniendo en cuenta que sólo se insertan los User que no existen en la base de datos. Si el elemento User ya existe en la base de datos no se hace nada.

Desde la **Activity** envío lo siguiente:

```
 UserRepository repo = new UserRepository(LoadingActivity.this);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                            
         if (!repo.existsUser(list.get(i))){
               repo.insert(list.get(i));
          }
    }
```

El **UserDao** consiste en lo siguiente:

```
@Query("select count(*) from users where name = :userName and email = :userEmail")
Single<Long> existsUser(int userName , String userEmail);
```

El **UserRepository** contiene lo siguiente:

```
private AppDatabase db;

public UserRepository(Context context){
    this.db  = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context);
}

public boolean existsUser(User item){

    final boolean[] existe = {false};

    db.userDao().existsUser(item.getName(), item.getEmail())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(query -> existe[0] = query > 0);

    return existe[0];
}

public void insert(User user){
    db.userDao().insert(user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }
            });
}
```

Siguiendo esta lógica debería asignar a `existe[0]` el valor true al insertar de nuevo e impedir que se inserte no obstante, la asignación `existe[0] = query > 0` se hace después del `return` de la función.

¿Es posible hacer en RXJava que se devuelva un valor? ¿Alguna otra orientación sobre cómo abordar lo que quiero hacer?

Comment: lo que tal vez podrias retornar es usuario como tal, de esa manera solo validas que si es null -> no existe y si tiene datos existe. Asimismo lo podrias usar para pintar algo en la vista.

Comment: hola! @PedroLumbre,  eso mismo intenté y el resultado fue el mismo. El hecho de utilizar una consulta COUNT(*) la tomé basada en comentarios a preguntas similares a la mía en las que lo recomendaban para obtener un "cero" si no existe o el número de ocurrencias si así las hubiera.